# How can I write a PHP script that will grab the follower count in Twitter for a given user?

Tags: php, mysql, json, twitter, twitter-oauth

All I want to do is get the Twitter follower count for a given user, say John Mayer. I want to store this value in a variable $testCount and that's it.  I'm not writing an application or anything with any other users (all the documentation seems to revolve around the assumption that other users will be doing this)

The reason I'm storing the value is because in my PHP script, all I want to do is store this value in a mySQL table.  Storing the value isn't the problem, it's retrieving it from Twitter's API. The eventual goal is to run this script every day and have it get an updated count of John Mayer's followers.

I've looked at other stack overflow answers and tried J7mbo's 'TwitterAPIExchange' method. So far I have this:

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');    // TwitterAPIExchange.php is in the same folder as the //script I am modifying

$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => " my token",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "my secret",
'consumer_key' => "my consumer key",
'consumer_secret' => "my consumer secret"
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=JohnMayer';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?screen_name=JohnMayer';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$follow_count=$twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest();
        $testCount = json_decode($follow_count, true);
echo $testCount[0]['user']['followers_count'];
```

the Echo simply doesn't print anything.  I've been working at this for days and can't seem to figure out how to grab this one statistic using php.  Please someone help me adjust or alter my current script to achieve this seemingly simple goal.

Comment: Does `echo '<pre>'.print_r($testCount,1).'</pre>';` print anything?

Comment: it prints the following: <pre>Array
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [message] => Bad Authentication data
                    [code] => 215
                )

        )

)
</pre>

Comment: Just read the error message.

Comment: Yes, its error 215 (bad authentication data).  I googled this error and there were also no solutions, but it seemed other people were having this issue

Comment: You should modify your URL to `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json` because this URL will be used in signature and URLs with parameters does not work on Twitter Authorization. Try this way.

Comment: this was a good idea, but the echo still prints nothing

Answer (score 0):

For anyone this might help, I figured it out. Here is my function that gets twitter followers, it is a modification on one from Codeforest but I took out a bunch of stuff involving something called cache.php and a bunch of other stuff that caused it to have errors.

```
function getTwitterFollowers($screenName = 'codeforest')
{
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
// this variables can be obtained in http://dev.twitter.com/apps
// to create the app, follow former tutorial on http://www.codeforest.net/get-twitter-follower-count
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "youraccesstoken",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "youraccesstokensecret",
    'consumer_key' => "yourconsumerkey",
    'consumer_secret' => "yourconsumersecret"
);



    // forming data for request
    $apiUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json";
    $requestMethod = 'GET';
    $getField = '?screen_name=' . $screenName;

    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $response = $twitter->setGetfield($getField)
         ->buildOauth($apiUrl, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest();

    $followers = json_decode($response);
    $numberOfFollowers = $followers->followers_count;


return $numberOfFollowers;
}
```

Now this code works, I can store the follower count in variable like so:
    $twitterfollow = getTwitterFollowers('dadalife');

Good luck to anyone else struggling with Twitter's new absurd API